# How do merge two EXE files with command prompt/C

Tags: c, windows, batch-file, cmd, exe

I've looked all over for a way to merge/bind 2 Windows executables with CMD and found nothing. My issue is I need to use only Windows Vista or above utilities to bind the EXE files. For example

```
COPY /B EXE1.EXE+EXE2.EXE EXE3.EXE
```

but have the programs start at the same time and this code only starts EXE1. Also, I can't use a BATCH file to do it like this

```
START EXE1.EXE
START EXE2.EXE
```

What I'm hoping for is a stub I can embed the CMD code into a C program and then use the C program as a stub (or even better if there is C code to do this) and extract the second program into a temporary directory then execute it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, are you saying that a small C program that executes these two executables would make you happy?

Comment: It sounds like you just want a self-extractor which is capable of automatically running a command after extraction?  Such self-extractors come with many popular compression utilities.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, that's what I need similar to how some computer viruses do it but I'm unsure how to do it. It needs to be completely self contained so using 7Zip or something to make it wouldn't work, it needs to only use Windows services or just C/BATCH code. I'm trying to break down how a computer virus could possibly work for educational reasons and I can't find any online documentation on it.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils No, that's not really what I want look at the comment right above this one.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to learn about exe injection.

Comment: @SomethingDark How does that work, is there any way I could do it in my own C project?

Comment: @QuaDECH hey you can use binders i have source if you want bind exe file with any file i can help you see binders exist in all internet [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=binders&oq=binders&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l2j69i60l2j69i59.921j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=binders+exe)

Comment: Just type "exe injection" into Google and you'll get tutorials. Basically, you're pasting the binary of one file into the empty space inside another file and then editing the assembly code to run the new file.

Comment: @SoheilHashemi Yeah if you have source that would be great

Comment: @SomethingDark I Googled it yesterday but I couldn't find anything else but info on it, I kind of understand it but I don't know how I could do that myself, there are programs that do it but I want to make my own. So basically I know what they are but I would have no idea how to start making one.

Comment: http://home.inf.fh-rhein-sieg.de/~ikarim2s/how2injectcode/code_inject.html - Literally the first result when you google `exe injection`

Comment: @SomethingDark I already saw that page when I Googled it but the thing is is I need to do it by myself in C. I can't use pre-made programs unless they come with Windows Vista or above as stated in the question, and it needs to be command line, figured I should state that also. It needs to spread on its own without recompiling.

Comment: @QuaDECH i post all solution check that in last solution you see my source code for binder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should know for your project all binder may be doesn't work well and possible devastated original exe

Method one you can use [qbc](http://www.abyssmedia.com/quickbfc/) very nice compiler for compile batch file to exe advantage in embedded file you can add any file to your exe

method two you can use rar for extracting before and after extraction which file extract and where very simple download [winrar](http://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=0) then select all your exe file check 'create SFX option' in advance tab go click on sfx option then in windows opened you should go setup tab and configure run after extraction and before extraction 
method three use [iexpress](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346760.aspx) microsoft tool 'create new self extraction file'you can make package for run multiple exe in one package tutorial exist in youtube but very simple wizard you can do it with out them !
method four you can use [sim](http://www.sminstall.com/download.html) create package and add multiple file and exe
 
method five you can making shortcut in that shortcut properties add batch file in batch file call all batch file you need it !
method six you can programming and make binder for merging file and add exe file i upload [my project](http://www.mediafire.com/download/fyptyo9ouo2t38r/Ultimate_File_Binder.rar) (c# language just project not executable file!)

Comment: Thanks, but it would need to be solid C, I guess I should have stated this but I'm compiling using only Linux with MinGW GCC. So I can't really do any thing like Visual Studio projects and I would prefer no C++ because of the size of EXEs it creates.

Comment: @QuaDech and i told you free way in windows something like iexpress  or batch file compiler just test them !

Comment: I think iExpress will work for my needs, thanks, sorry I didn't see that before.

Answer (score 1):

EXEs cannot be combined in this fashion. Text files, or binaries that are expected to be combined like this can use this method.

EXEs are [portable executables](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). They need to follow the format specified in order for them to work.

If you're looking to run multiple EXEs, try writing a batch script, or if you must have a single EXE and have the code, you can write your code so that you compile into a single EXE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what I was looking for is come kind of self-extractor I can create in C/BATCH, sorry that I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a small program that calls one of the exec* family of functions.  Call it twice, once for each of the executable files to be run.

then, just run the program you just wrote, letting it do the work

Comment: There's no calling an `exec` function twice, not unless the first call fails. I think you mean `spawn`.